# When should my prism services be registered?

Tags: mvvm, service, prism, unity-container, bootstrapper

I've been struggling with the ideal approach to this. Right now, I have my services created in Boostrapper right before I create my application shell, in the method:

```
protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
```

After my shell gets created, I then create all my view models, passing the services they need.

So firstly, I want to know if that's a good practice. Also, I've tried to find examples of declaring services inside a .config file, but I really didn't see any. Is this not a good practice either?

Example:

```
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        appWnd = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ApplicationWindow>();
        Container.RegisterInstance<ILicensing>(new LicensingService());
        Container.RegisterInstance<IAnotherService>(new AnotherService());

        return appWnd;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I have my services created in Boostrapper"? Do you create instances or do you register the types in a container? Can you post the method? Anyhow, the method CreateShell() should do not more than creating the shell ;)

Comment: Edited my post to include an example. I create the instances of the service inside the CreateShell() method. Where would be the appropriate place to register these services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method ConfigureContainer() of the UnityBootstrapper is supposed to be overridden to do what you are asking for:

> **MSDN - ConfigureContainer:**
>
> Both the Composite Application Library and the applications built on
>   top of it depend on a container for injecting required dependencies.
>   During the container configuration phase, several core services are
>   registered, as shown in the following code from the UnityBootstrapper.

[MSDN on UnityBootstrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921139%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx)

The MSDN example:

```
protected virtual void ConfigureContainer()
{
    …
    if (useDefaultConfiguration)
    {
        RegisterTypeIfMissing(typeof(IServiceLocator), typeof(UnityServiceLocatorAdapter), true);
        RegisterTypeIfMissing(typeof(IModuleInitializer), typeof(ModuleInitializer), true);
        RegisterTypeIfMissing(typeof(IModuleManager), typeof(ModuleManager), true);
        RegisterTypeIfMissing(typeof(RegionAdapterMappings), typeof(RegionAdapterMappings), true);
        RegisterTypeIfMissing(typeof(IRegionManager), typeof(RegionManager), true);
        RegisterTypeIfMissing(typeof(IEventAggregator), typeof(EventAggregator), true);
        RegisterTypeIfMissing(typeof(IRegionViewRegistry), typeof(RegionViewRegistry), true);
        RegisterTypeIfMissing(typeof(IRegionBehaviorFactory), typeof(RegionBehaviorFactory), true);
    }
}
```

You can also register instances here, etc., using `Container` directly, as you already do.

The CreateShell() method is not the place to do this, as you should do nothing more than creating the shell here.

So, in short, just override ConfigureCatalog() and paste your code there.

Comment: Also, is there an advantage from registering instances vs types?

Comment: In general, you should prefer registering types over registering instances. It's the containers job to create the instances and distributing it to those who need it. Registering instances can be useful though, especially when you just happen to have an instance of the service for whatever reasons and you want to use it in the container. Not really a scientific answer, but you get the point: I would keep it clean, let the container to its job, unless there are really good reasons not to. I'm happy I could help, have fun.