# WPF Prism access to defined info like some class objects inside Module from main project

Tags: c#, wpf, prism-4

I have a `WPF Prism` solution in `VS` and want keep some settings of my `prism` `module` inside an object in the module project (i load this settings from a file), then i created my `prism` `module` class (`AModule.cs`) like this:

**Inside my module project (`AModul` project):**

```
[Export]
[Module(ModuleName = "AModule")]
public class AModule : IModule
{
    ModuleSettingsModel ModuleSettings { get ; set; }

    public AModule()
    {
        // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public AModule(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        // Some codes ....
    }

    ~AModule()
    {
        // some codes
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        var regionManager = _container.Resolve<IRegionManager>();
        regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("WorkspaceRegion", typeof(ModuleAView));


        ModuleSettings = DataFileManager.LoadModuleData();
    }
```

It works well and i can use my settings inside `AModule`

---

**Inside `Main WPF Project`:**

But i need access this settings (`ModuleSettings` property) in my `Main WPF project` too. For example i need access to `ModuleA`»`ModuleSettings` in my `Bootstrapper` class of my `WPF` application. I need do some workd base on each module settings in my main project...

> My question is what solutions are there to do? Should i register any type? Where? How?

---

**Note1:** ModuleSettings* is inherited from `IModuleSettings` and `IModuleSettings` is inside `Infrastructure project`.

**Note2:** I load my modules dynamically into prism (my main `WPf` project has not any reference to `AModule`);

Comment: In my projects I use a custom attribute to decorate my model with information about resources that have to be loaded in global context. You could do that with your settings too. Just check your modules for these settings when you register them. Another way to hold your Settings in a global context would be some kind of settings provider you register before you load any module. In your module you can resolve that provider and register your Settings.

Comment: @BenedikSchroeder, thank u, I need 2 simple examples about your 2 solution. I need know how to do these ways, how and where register new types. May you please write an answer include some usefull information about these solution. Also reffrense links to some external samples and articles can help me...

Answer (score 2):

You should put the ModuleSettings into a class library project that is referenced by the various modules/projects. You could use the singleton pattern to only load and maintain one instance of the settings.

Comment: No, I won't any refference.... I need access full dynamically to some created object in my modules. I think Prism has some facility to doing this.

Comment: thank you, I meant won't new class library and another reference, but your way is correct but your answer didn't helped me about "Where" and "How" that was in my question.

Answer (score 0):

After read [GlenThomas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31666688/wpf-prism-access-to-defined-info-like-some-class-objects-inside-module-from-main#31671288) &  @BenediktSchroeder's first comment in question and reading some additional references like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921149.aspx) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231652/when-should-my-prism-services-be-registered), i could found & implement a good way for my question:

> I solved it by adding a new custom `Prism Service`

1. Create an Interface for our service class (eq. `ISettingManager`) in `Infrastructure Project`. Modules and Main App need reference to `Infrastructure Project`
2. Create an Class for our service (eq. `SettingManager`)
3. Define one property in `ISettingManager` to keep `ModuleSetting` like:

   `Dictionary<string,ModuleSettingsModel> ModuleSettingsPairs{get;set;}`
4. Add some methods in `ISettingManager` to `Get`, `Add` and `Remove` setting to/from the `ModuleSettingsPairs` dictionary.
5. Register the new service type in `ConfigureContainer` inside the `bootstraper` as `Singlton` like:

   `RegisterTypeIfMissing(typeof(IAddonSettingsManager), typeof(AddonSettingsManager), true);`
6. Obtain reference to the `IAddonSettingsManager` service instance in the `module project` or `main app project`, it can do by one of following ways:

   - Declaratively obtain references to services using constructor injection
   - Programmatically obtain references to services (by use the `Resolve` method of the `Unity container`)
7. Finally, play with custom `Get`, `Add` and `Remove` methods of our service instance (`SettingManager`)

Comment: That is what i ment and in my opinion a clean solution.